# Is there a [Google App script] method like Application.Intersect(Target, Range) in Excel VBA?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

```
#VBA 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Range("A2:M10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
Range("N" & Target.Row).Value = Format(Now)

End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Well, What I want is
to indicate the time of correction or input
whenever the corresponding range is modified or entered for each column.

**Here`s Question** : If someone did something similar, please share your experience. If he can be reanimated, I will adapt him to solve my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use **onEdit** Trigger to have the same functionality in app-script also,

Based on available VBA Code, go to appscript editor through your google sheet and try this :

```
function onEdit(e) {   
    var range = e.range; // Get edited range
    var row = range.getRow() //  Get edited row from range
    var column = range.getColumn() //  Get edited column from range
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ssname = ss.getActiveSheet()
    if(row >= 2 && column <= 13) // Only add timestamp if edit occured in A2:M
    {
      ssname.getRange('N'+row).setValue(new Date()) // Adding Timestamp in N column
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

[onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: Hello Sir, I`m so happy for your answer. I ran your script and there's error : ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`  At Line2, I defined `range` as `e.range;`..

Comment: That's because onEdit trigger have that event object e, and when you run it directly it doesn't contain any items inside that is why it is throwing that error, try editing the sheet where this script is bound to, just like you're doing in excel.